# Interpretation of homework requirements, involving client/server communication

Tags: c++

I've been working on an assignment that asks us to implement some code provided to us that allows the creation of a server and client that can communicate.  I was to fork a process in main, and then test the various request options available, and then measure the difference in time it took to do this via the child process, or locally using a function.  I'm unsure if I've interpretated the requirements correctly though.  On top of this, all the timing functions return 0 seconds. Not sure if this is correct or not. I'll post a small portion of the code.

Homework statement (only a small portion):

> Measure the invocation delay of a request (i.e. the time between the
>   invocation of a request until the response comes back.) Compare that
>   with the time to submit the same request string to a function that
>   takes a request and returns a reply (as compared to a separate process
>   that does the same). Submit a report that compares the two.

The function declared before main:

```
string myfunc(string request){
  //string myreq = request;
  RequestChannel my_func_channel("control", RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
  string reply1 = my_func_channel.send_request(request);
  return reply1;
}
```

And how I interpreted the directions in code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  //time variables
  time_t start, end;
  double time_req_1, time_req_func;

  cout << "client.C  Starting...\n" << flush;
  cout << "Forking new process...\n " << flush;      
  pid_t childpid = fork();

  if(childpid == -1)
    cout << "Failed to fork.\n" << flush;
  else if(childpid == 0){
    cout << "***Loading Dataserver...\n" << flush;
    //Load dataserver   
    RequestChannel my_channel("control", RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
    cout << "***Dataserver Loaded.\n" << flush;

    time(&start);
    string reply1 = my_channel.send_request("hello");
    cout << "***Reply to request 'hello' is '" << reply1 << "'\n" << flush;
    time(&end);
    time_req_1 = difftime(end,start);  

    cout <<"\n\nRequest 1 took     :  "<< time_req_1 << flush;

  }
  else{//parent
    time(&start);
    string s = myfunc("hello");
    time(&end);
    time_req_func = difftime(end,start);
    cout <<"\nmyfunc Request took:  "<< time_req_func << "\n" << flush;

  }
  usleep(1000000);
}
```

This is an abbreviated version of my code, but contains everything you should need to figure out whats going on.  Have I done what the directions stated?  Also, is it likely that my 0 seconds results are correct?

Comment: `time` typically only has seconds-level granularity, which I doubt is precise enough for what you're trying to achieve. Look into using a high-resolution timer such as that in [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono/).

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes to do it once may be (probably is) too small to measure, so time how long it takes to do it many times and then work out how long each one took.

Comment: I will do this.  Next thing is, do you feel like the code matches the directions?